# How can I run queries concurrently in Snowflake

Tags: sql, concurrency, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can i run some set a select queries in snowflake concurrently. When i write query and running it it runs one by one, but i want all the query to start at same time..

Can anybody help me on this.
Thanks in advance
Regards
Saswati.

Comment: How are you running the queries now? through the Python / JDBC drivers or through the web interface?

Comment: Is this part of some sort of benchmarking?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do this, some of them are:

- Create a [`TASK`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/create-task.html) for each query and schedule for the same time
- Use an external tool (eg ETL tool) capable of running multiple queries in parallel
- Write a script (eg Python) using eg [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#module-threading)